Error 504: Upstream Request Timeout in Serverless Backend of Load Balancer
Introduction: In a setup where CloudRun services are accessed via private IP through a load balancer, I'm encountering a timeout restriction of 15 seconds when invoking the private IP from a virtual machine (VM). This timeout is significantly short, my CloudRun function executes in about 30 seconds to 1 minute.
VM (private network) => invoke private ip => via loadbalancer (url mapping...etc) => cloudrun
Issue Description:
Utilizing a load balancer to access CloudRun services via private IP.
The timeout for CloudRun services is set to 5 minutes (300 seconds) for handling incoming requests.
However, when invoking the private IP from a VM, a maximum timeout of 15 seconds is enforced.
Latencies exceeding this 15-second limit result in a 504 error response.
Default resource timeout for serverless backend services is 1 hour
`
data "google_cloud_run_service" "cloudrun_api" {
    provider = google-beta
    location = "us-central1"
    name     = var.cloudrun_service
}
resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "cloudrun_api" {
    provider = google-beta
    name     = "serverless-cloudrun-api"
    region   = "us-central1"
    cloud_run {
        service = data.google_cloud_run_service.cloudrun_api.name

    }
}

# Begin: Configure internal load balancing for cloudrun API

resource "google_compute_backend_service" "cloudrun_api" {
    provider                        = google-beta
    name                            = "lb-be-cloudrun-api"
    connection_draining_timeout_sec = 300
    load_balancing_scheme           = "INTERNAL_MANAGED"
    port_name                       = "http"
    protocol                        = "HTTP"
    session_affinity                = "NONE"
    locality_lb_policy              = "ROUND_ROBIN"

    backend {
        group = google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.cloudrun_api.self_link
    }
}

resource "google_compute_url_map" "cloudrun_api" {
    provider        = google-beta
    name            = "lb-cloudrun-api"
    default_service = google_compute_backend_service.cloudrun_api.id
    path_matcher {
        name            = "lb-cloudrun-path"
        default_service = google_compute_backend_service.cloudrun_api.id
        path_rule {
            paths   = ["/*"]
            service = google_compute_backend_service.cloudrun_api.id
            route_action {
              timeout {
                  seconds = 80
              }
            }
        }

    }
}

resource "google_compute_target_http_proxy" "cloudrun_api" {
    provider = google-beta
    name     = "http-lb-proxy-cloudrun-api"
    url_map  = google_compute_url_map.cloudrun_api.id
}


resource "google_compute_address" "cloudrun_api" {
    provider     = google-beta
    address      = "10.128.x.x"
    name         = "lb-ipv4-cloudrun-api"
    ip_version   = "IPV4"
    address_type = "INTERNAL"
    purpose      = "GCE_ENDPOINT"
    subnetwork   = data.google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork.name
}
resource "google_compute_global_forwarding_rule" "cloudrun_api" {
    provider              = google-beta
    name                  = "http-content-rule-cloudrun-api"
    ip_protocol           = "TCP"
    load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL_MANAGED"
    port_range            = "80-80"
    target                = google_compute_target_http_proxy.cloudrun_api.id
    ip_address            = google_compute_address.cloudrun_api.address
}`

When I try with the public URL of the Cloud Run function, it works well. Can I ask which network component restricts the timeout to 15 seconds, and how can I increase it?
I also do not use openapi and espv2
https://ibb.co/dPxZDJF
